# Error: "Unable to choose a more specific candidate" when using Rider and new csproj structure

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, csproj, rider

I get an error in Rider that say: "Unable to choose a more specific candidate. Candidates are: Public Function Foo (in Class Enumerable) Public Function Foo (in Class Enumerable)".

This only happen in projects where we have updated the csproj file to the "new" structure/format.

The error is shown as a complier error but the code compiles just fine and if I open the solution in Visual Studio I get no error.

My suspicion is that this might be a false error somehow in Rider.

Is there a workaround for this or is there another solution (maybe some setting that overrides this being shown)?